# Running springboot using maven vs. via java directly?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jvm

Essentially, the Jenkins CI job runs `mvn spring-boot:run ....` in a productions cluster as the only way to run the application. With this build step, in effect, we are running the springboot app only via maven and this has led to a very unstable jvm behavior. Also, I am unable to configure all the possible tweaks to the jvm e.g, turning on gc logging or changing to G1GC etc.. etc..

I just wanted to know if running my java springboot app should indeed be packaged into a fat jar and run with standard jvm flags, rather than from maven.

Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot maven plugin has `jvmArguments` in order to set `jvm` settings.

```
......
<configuration>
    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug</jvmArguments>
</configuration>
.......
```

The second option is to create a self-executable jar/war and use a standard way to run app -  `java -jar app.jar <jvm properties>`

Comment: Sure. But isn't running maven just to run a springboot java app an overhead ? I am running this in app in a cluster...

Comment: @ZeroGraviti You have an option to create a self executable jar/war and run it via standard way `java -jar app.jar` and your properties as console arguments.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 0):

Our teams have been running fat jars similar to how others have stated with the simple `java -jar ****.jar` commands. However, once in production, you can utilize a container clustering system to construct the many microservices that make up your app. Seems like running maven and deploying source code, rather than artifacts seems dangerous. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I do agree. What kind of CI/CD pipeline do you use ? We are using Jenkins. Any suggestion around IAC tooling or good old shell scripts ? (We really aren't looking at Kubernetes or Docker or Mesos etc... and no AWS for prod.)

Comment: Jenkins Pipelines seems to solve many of other issues you may have when trying to accomplish CI/CD. Take a look at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/